# error while converting command line arguments to a dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am tring to convert the cmd line arguments into a dictionary. The code I am using for this purpose

```
import sys

cmd_line_args = dict(arg.split('=') for arg in sys.argv[1:])
```

I am calling this function in command line by

```
python python_basics.py p1=param1 p2="param 2" p3=param3
```

But I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_basics.py", line 23, in <module>
    temp_dict = dict(arg.split('='))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Is there any wrong in the way I am trying to convert arguments to dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

`dict` expects an iterable of two-item iterables

so, `cmd_line_args = dict([arg.split('=') for arg in sys.argv[1:]])` has resolved my issue